# How to watch values of vector in Kdevelop debugger

Tags: ubuntu

I know that with `VisualStudio`, there are more possibilities to view the values in a `std::vector v`, like `v._first, 100` -> displays the first 100 elements, or changing some log file. Is there a way to do this in `KDevelop` under `Ubuntu 14.04`?